# Return row names of dataframe meeting condition stored in list using lapply

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I have a list containing data frames, each with varying observations. Here is an example of what I am working with:

```
set.seed(9)
df<- data.frame(x1 = round(runif(80, 0, 5)),
                x2 = round(runif(80, 0, 15)),
                x3 = sample(letters[1:8], 80, replace = TRUE))
my.list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 8)                            
my.list <- lapply(unique(df$x3), function(x) {subset(df, x3 == x)})
```

What I am trying to achieve is to find the row names of each data frame for which a condition is met. Using `lapply()` the nearest I have got to what I want to achieve is with the code below.  However, this returns NA's; I am not sure why this happens.

```
> lapply(my.list, function(x) {x <- row.names(x[which(x[,1:2] < 5), ]); x})[[1]]
 [1] "1"    "5"    "11"   "22"   "46"   "53"   "61"   "63"   "64"   "79"   "80"   "NA"   "NA.1" "NA.2" "NA.3"
```

What needs to be done so that only the row names are returned?

Comment: You can make this change in your code and the na's will go away.
`lapply(my.list, function(x) {x <- row.names(x[which(x[,1:2][1] < 5), ]); x})`
Note: I added the [1] inside the which statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `lapply(my.list, function(x) {x <- row.names(x[which(x[,1:2] < 5), ]); x})`

with this below to make sure only the subset list go into the row.names call

```
lapply(my.list, function(x) {x <- row.names(x[which(x[,1:2][1] < 5), ]); x})
```

Comment: Thank you. So simple, so elegant. @XXavier

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do:

```
v = lapply(my.list, function(x) {
                y <- rowSums(x[,1:2] < 5) == 2
                names(y[y == T])
          })

print(v)

[[1]]
[1] "1"  "13" "65"

[[2]]
[1] "20" "48" "58" "63"

[[3]]
[1] "3"  "43"

[[4]]
[1] "5"  "12" "24" "77" "80"

[[5]]
[1] "8"  "31"

[[6]]
[1] "25"

[[7]]
[1] "17" "19" "23" "49" "60" "62"

[[8]]
[1] "15" "30" "40"
```

Comment: Thank you, a nice alternative! @YOLO